# RemoveEventListener doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, svg, event-handling, event-listener

I attached an event listener to my SVG image in order to perform some code after the image has been loaded. As it sometimes happens, a bug might occur in my SVG generating code and the SVG file won't load. In that case, when user clicks another button, I want it to remove the event listener, hide the unsuccessful result and let the user select another SVG image.

Here's what I have:

```js
// In external .js file, loaded prior to the other code in <head>
function setResultViewBox() {
  var objectEl = document.getElementById("resultImage");
  var svgDoc = objectEl.contentDocument;
  var svg = svgDoc.childNodes[0];
  // If there's no SVG tag, remove the listener etc. 
  // Tested via alert() and console messages that this actually works.
  if (svg.tagName !== "svg") {
    editBrush();
    return;
  }
  // some other code to set the viewBox
}

// Attached to the main file at the end of <body>
var resultImage = document.getElementById("resultImage");

    function resultImageLoaded(event) {
      resultImage.removeEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
      setResultViewBox();
      hideProgressBar();
    }

    submitChanges() {
      // Compute URI here
      resultImage.data = uri;
      resultImage.addEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
      hidePreview();
    }

    function editBrush() {
      alert();
      resultImage.removeEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
      hideResult();
      hideProgressBar();
    }
```

```html
<object id="resultImage" type="image/svg+xml" width="420" height="420" data=""></object>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitChanges()">Make outline</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editBrush()">Edit brush</a>
```

This came to me as a surprise: for once, in Internet Explorer 11, it does exactly what I want it to do; on the other hand, in Opera it doesn't work (the hell must have frozen I guess).

Testing it on an image case I know for sure it won't load, it attempts to set the viewBox of the result image, fails to find the `<svg>` tag, throws an alert message as it goes to editBrush(), removes the listener and allows me to select another SVG file, which it loads correctly then. That means it creates the listener once again, loads the correct URI, recognizes `<svg>` tag, sets viewBox, removes the listener in the `resultImageLoaded(event)` itself and all is good.

In Opera, it attempts to set the viewBox of the result image, fails to find the `<svg>` tag, throws an alert message as it goes to editBrush() and I suspect now it doesn't actually remove the listener. When I select another SVG image, which it should load correctly now, nothing happens (tried to add another alert to `resultImageLoaded(event)` and it wasn't triggered).

Things I gave special attention to:

- `resultImageLoaded(event)` isn't an anonymous function and is located above the code that is using it
- reference to the function itself in the add/remove listeners
- resultImage is stored in one variable and both add/remove listeners are on this one object

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, any help would be most appreciated.

**EDIT:** In console in Opera, it shows Internal server error (500) on GET request when I try to load the image that should fail loading. IE shows no such thing. Not sure if this can be of any help.

**EDIT 2:** Alright, I just found out this has probably nothing to do with removeEventListener(). Even when I comment out all lines where I remove event listeners, the behaviour is exactly the same as described in both browsers. Could the problem be in Opera reporting an error and IE ignoring it?

---

And question for mods: when I find out the original question's topic is no more relevant, but the problem still persists and I'm not even sure what might be causing it, what do I do? Brutally edit the original question or make a new one and leave the original one unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `event.stopPropagation();` at the end of each `eventListener`, this will prevent bubbling of the event to your ancestors and it'll stop at your `event.target`

If that doesn't help, try `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm

```js
// In external .js file, loaded prior to the other code in <head>
function setResultViewBox() {
  var objectEl = document.getElementById("resultImage");
  var svgDoc = objectEl.contentDocument;
  var svg = svgDoc.childNodes[0];
  // If there's no SVG tag, remove the listener etc. 
  // Tested via alert() and console messages that this actually works.
  if (svg.tagName !== "svg") {
    editBrush();
    return;
  }
  // some other code to set the viewBox
}

// Attached to the main file at the end of <body>
var resultImage = document.getElementById("resultImage");

    function resultImageLoaded(event) {
      resultImage.removeEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
      setResultViewBox();
      hideProgressBar();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    submitChanges() {
      // Compute URI here
      resultImage.data = uri;
      resultImage.addEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
      hidePreview();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    function editBrush() {
      alert();
      resultImage.removeEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
      hideResult();
      hideProgressBar();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

```html
<object id="resultImage" type="image/svg+xml" width="420" height="420" data=""></object>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitChanges()">Make outline</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editBrush()">Edit brush</a>
```

Comment: Neither of this works, but I appreciate your effort anyway. I also have a question: does the event bubble to the ancestors even if it's attached directly to the `resultImage`, no parents/children involved? Just to clarify, this is the only event listener I have in the entire document.

Comment: When an event bubbles up it's going up the chain of elements, so if your button is clicked (`event.target`), then it travels up to the button's parent element (e.g. form), then onto that element's parent (the button's grandparent?), and so on all the way up to `window`. There's the reverse that happens from the window all the way down to `event.target` called the capturing phase. By default the event starts down to the `event.target` from the window but ignores all the elements, this is the capturing phase. The capturing phase can be changed by `obj.addEventListener('click', readyFunc, true);`

Comment: Bubbling happens after the event has reached `event.target` and by default will actually trigger any listeners along the way up to the window. To change that behavior you use `event.stopPropagation();` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`. The reason why you might want to do this is because it's wasteful or disruptive to have multiple elements firing on an event you just needed to fire once.